# How to Return Commutative Sum of specific INT Column's Values?

Tags: stored-functions

For Example we created Column Name "Meow", It has nth number of rows. LET Suppose values are 32, 67, 89, .... Now I want to Show the Column Name Name "Boy Cat" where it shows the Commutative Sum w.r.t "Meow" Column.

**Note:** "Boy Cat" Column was not created while creating"Meow" Column. I just Want to Make this Column in Query as stored function or without stored function.

I am expecting that It Return

| MEOW | BOY CAT |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | 32 |
| 67 | 109 |
| 89 | 198 |
| ... | (198+ ..) |

Logic Behind (0 + 32) in first Row, (32 + 67) in 2nd Row,
(109 + 89) in 3rd Row for "Boy Cat".